# What does "static assertion failed" mean when building Assimp?

Tags: c++, assimp

I am trying to build Assimp with cmake and mingw and when it tries to build `FBXExporter.cpp.obj` (55% in the building process) it stops and shows this error:

`static assertion failed: TRIED TO CREATE FBX PROPERTY WITH UNSUPPORTED TYPE, CHECK YOUR PROPERTY INSTANTIATION`
`static_assert(std::is_void<T>::value, "TRIED TO CREATE FBX PROPERTY WITH UNSUPPORTED TYPE, CHECK YOUR PROPERTY INSTANTIATION");`.
What does it mean and how can I fix this?
I am really new to graphics programming and this is my first time building a library.

Answer (score 0):

This is a compile-time assertion. During the compilation a type was found which could not be resolved by the compiler. The check:

```
std::is_void<T>::value
```

will return true if a void type was detected. I guess this was caused by some incompatibilities of the compiler and the source. To solve this we need more information about the followings things:

1. Version of assimp-lib you have tried to build
2. Version of your mingw-compiler
3. The line-number where this build-failure has occurred.

The best way is to open an issue report with these information on the project-side.